# Width and precision format for Float numbers to a string

Tags: c, width, precision, mask

I need to perform a seemingly simple manipulation but I can't seem to make it work.
What I need to do is format a float number to a number with exact thre digits of decimal width and two digits of precision.

```
320.1 -> 320.10
320 -> 320.00
32.1 -> 032.10
```

i tried something like

```
sprintf(cbuffer, "%03.2f", (float)32);
```

but it doesn't work. I'm using visual studio 2010 on windows 8.1 and the project must be run on Windows platform (i don't know if it differs to unix-based systems)
Also, is there a simpler way to make it work in c++?

Comment: You left out the data type specifier. `"%03.2"` should be, for example, `"%03.2f"`. It's the same on any common platform that `sprintf` or `printf` are used in C or C++.

Comment: i got it. the number preceded by 0 is the number of chars. In my case, since the maximum number will always be 6 chars long, the correct mask is %06.2
thanks!

Comment: Yep. check the ample online documentation for "printf format string".

Comment: believe it or not, but I spent some time searching for this. I'm not new at c programming, currently working on multithreading for a CLP alarm decoder program, but I failed to understand the meaning of the width modulator. I thought it was supposed to work only for the left, decimal part of the mask. I am sorry for the dumb questions. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct mask for this case is %06.2. this way

```
printf("%06.2f", (float)32); //correction pointed out by @lurker
```

will print

```
032.00
```

Comment: You're still missing the data type specifier. `f` in this case.

Comment: whops, true. I did it right in my project though, but wrote the answer fast.